# How to pass props through Route without loosing them after refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am passing userId extracted from TextField in Login.js from Login.js to Company.js to Dashboard.js once the user is authenticated.

Login.js

```
class Login extends Component {

  state = {
    //state
  }

  loginHandler = (event) => {
     //authentication check
    this.props.history.push({
              pathname: '/company/dashboard',
              state:{
                  userId: this.state.username,
              }
         });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      //html code
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Company.js

```
class Company extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super();
        console.log(props.history.location.state.userId)
        this.state = {
            userId: props.history.location.state.userId
        }
    }

    drawerList = {
        'Profile':['profile', <DashboardIcon />],
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Dashboard userId={this.state.userId} drawerList={this.drawerList}>
                     <Route exact path="/company/dashboard/profile" component={Profile} />
                </Dashboard>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(Company);
```

Dashboard.js

```
function ClippedDrawer(props) {
    const buttonHandler = (text) => {
        props.history.push(props.match.path + '/' + props.drawerList[text][0]);
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                        PICT PLACEMENT - {props.history.location.state.userId}
                    </Typography>
    );
}

export default withRouter(ClippedDrawer);
```

Everything is working fine in first go. I login with userId and pass it takes me to company dashboard but if I refresh company dashboard page:

TypeError: props.history.location.state is undefined (in Company.js)

Is it because once refreshed state is lost? How should I pass userId so that it remains even after refresh or do I need to use sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State is fundamentally not stored on refresh, which only keeps the url itself. You have two options:

## Store the user ID in URL

This option has the advantage that a user can change his own user id

Change the route to

```
<route path="/company/dashboard/:user_id">
```

In `Company`, use `props.params.user_id` instead of `props.state.user_id`

And replace this:

```
this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/company/dashboard',
          state:{
              userId: this.state.username,
          }
     });
```

With this:

```
this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/company/dashboard/'+userId,
     });
```

## Store the user in Cookies or Local Storage

instead of doing `props.state.user_id` with `localStorage.getItem(user_id)`. Use `localStorage.setItem` to properly update the user id in the login component.

This method has the advantage that the user cannot see his ID, and if he logs in and out the id's will stay the same.

Comment: Is any one method better than the other one? I found using localStorage easier.

Comment: It really depends on the situation. The first option is 'cleaner' in my opinion, and allows the user to navigate back to the page with the parameter set. The second option makes it a bit more difficult for the user to manually change the value. It depends on the situation which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Store the user info inside the local storage. U can install it via npm. So it wont be cleaned after refresh. So with a basic if statement if local storage includes user info pass that one as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history, props.history.location.state is mutable and so you should use the prop location.

This is how they've explained:

> It is also found on history.location but you shouldn’t use that
> because it’s mutable. You can read more about that in the history doc.
> A location object is never mutated so you can use it in the lifecycle
> hooks to determine when navigation happens, this is really useful for
> data fetching and animation